# How to remove extra words/characters from title?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using Cheerio to text the title text from the title tag from the following link:

```
https://www.starbucks.com.sg/coffeehouse/store-locator#
```

In the html title tag, contains the following text below.

```
Store Locator | Starbucks Coffee Company
```

However, when I used Cheerio to extract, there seems to be an extra character that did not even existed inside the html title tag in the first place. There should not be an issue.

```
const title =  $("title").text();
/* Outputs the following instead:
Store Locator | Starbucks Coffee Company
   FacebookTwitterWhatsAppEmail
*/
```

Comment: show html page code and js code

Answer (score 0):

You want to obtain the `<title>` tag text from the `<head>` of the document without any additional white-space? Just access the title element directly and trim the text.

That's easy, it's just:

```js
let title = document.title.trim(); // "Store Locator | Starbucks Coffee Company"
```

Comment: yes correct. But the problem here is not the white space. But rather the extra characters `FacebookTwitterWhatsAppEmail` that is being extracted

Comment: @scorezel789 I just visited that page and I did not get that text, are you running any browser extensions or something?